# can sent email through pickup folder also appear in SENT ITEM in OUTLOOK

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, email

I am generating .eml files and send them by placing them in Pickup folder.
I there any way to make the emails appear in Sent item in Outlook.

I'm sending it using smtp btw.

Comment: If you want them in your sent items in outlook - why not send them through outlook?

Comment: Won't they appear after they are sent when Outlook sync's with the server?

Comment: Unless you do some Outlook Interop, I believe you cannot accomplish that.Is it the outlook sent folder a requirement? Outlook interop is not the most manteinable choice, you are tied to having Outlook installed in the machine. Other choices dont require paying MS licences

Comment: The email is generated in an application that has modified functionalities such as attaching files easily by simply selecting those files from the list.